# Wrong behavior in a button located in each row of a list when I change the orientation of a tablet

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button, android-adapter

I have a custom SimpleCursorAdapter and a list view. Each row of the list have a name and a button. When I press the button for each name, a dialog appears with a description.
Inside the custom  SimpleCursorAdapter I set the onclick method for the button. When I have a large list, my listView gets a scroll bar. And I dont know why, when I scroll down, the last rows of my list doesnt show the correct description for each row. This is my code:

```
public class listServicesCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

private Context context;
private int layout;
private String[] from;
private int[] to;


public listServicesCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    //Column of BD that we want to recover
    String column = null;

    //Index of the column of  DB
    int nameCol = 0;

    //Result of obtain the index of the column of DB 
    String nombre = null;

    //Name of the textView in the Layout where we want to show the result
    TextView name_text= null;

    String description = null;
    String nameService = null;

    //For each value of DB, we show it in the text view.
    for (int i=0; i<from.length; i++){
        column= from[i];
        nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(column);
        name = cursor.getString(nameCol);

        //the values to[i] equals to 0 indicates values that we need but 
                    //that we are not showing in the list directly
        //0 -> description
        if(to[i] == 0){
            description = name;
        }else{
            nameService = name; 
            name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (name_text != null) {
                name_text.setText(name);
            }
        }
    }


    ImageButton buttonDescription = (ImageButton)  v.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDescription);

    //we store in a bundle the name and description of the service, so we can use it in
            // the setOnClickListener method.
    final Bundle mArguments = new Bundle();
    mArguments.putString("name", nameService);
    mArguments.putString("description", description);



    buttonDescription .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

            builder.setMessage(mArguments.getString("description"))
            .setTitle(mArguments.getString("name"))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }});

    return v;
}
```

}

This is where I call the adapter:

```
        ServiceSqliteDao serviceDao = new ServiceSqliteDao();
            //get the services for DB
    Cursor mCursorServices = serviceDao.listServices(getActivity());


    if(mCursorServices.getCount()>0){
        //indicate the fields we want to show (from) and where (to)
        String[] from = new String[] { "name", "description"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.checkBoxService,0};
        ListView lvServices = (ListView) v.findViewById (R.id.listViewServices);

        ListServicesCursorAdapter notes = new ListServicesCursorAdapter (getActivity(), R.layout.activity_file_service, mCursorServices, from, to, 0);
        lvServices.setAdapter(notes);
```

Why do I get this behavior?. I get all the names in the list right but when I press the button in horizontal way (I mean a put the tablet horizontally) and get the scroll bar in my list, I dont get the right description. By the other hand, if I use the tablet vertically, I dont get the scroll bar in my list and I get the right description in each button.

This is my layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewServices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

**SOLUTION:**
newView should look like this:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    return v;
}
```

and bindView should look like this:

```
@Override
public View bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    //Column of BD that we want to recover
    String column = null;

    //Index of the column of  DB
    int nameCol = 0;

    //Result of obtain the index of the column of DB 
    String nombre = null;

    //Name of the textView in the Layout where we want to show the result
    TextView name_text= null;

    String description = null;
    String nameService = null;

    //For each value of DB, we show it in the text view.
    for (int i=0; i<from.length; i++){
        column= from[i];
        nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(column);
        name = cursor.getString(nameCol);

        //the values to[i] equals to 0 indicates values that we need but 
                    //that we are not showing in the list directly
        //0 -> description
        if(to[i] == 0){
            description = name;
        }else{
            nameService = name; 
            name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (name_text != null) {
                name_text.setText(name);
            }
        }
    }

/********************************NEW CODE ************************************/

String uniMedition = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("unitMedition"));
    if(uniMedition.equals("none")){
        EditText etMedida = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextMedida);
        etMedida.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        TextView tvUniMedition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUniMedition);
        tvUniMedition .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }else{
        EditText etMedida = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextMedida);
        etMedida.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        TextView tvUniMedition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUniMedition);
        tvUniMedition .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvUniMedition .setText(uniMedition);

    }

/********************************END NEW CODE ************************************/

    ImageButton buttonDescription = (ImageButton)  v.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDescription);

    //we store in a bundle the name and description of the service, so we can use it in
            // the setOnClickListener method.
    final Bundle mArguments = new Bundle();
    mArguments.putString("name", nameService);
    mArguments.putString("description", description);



    buttonDescription .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

            builder.setMessage(mArguments.getString("description"))
            .setTitle(mArguments.getString("name"))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }});

}
```

}

Now everything works fine!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I get this behavior?. I get all the names in the list right but
>   when I press the button in horizontal way (I mean a put the tablet
>   horizontally) and get the scroll bar in my list, I dont get the right
>   description.

When your `ListView` doesn't have space to show all of the rows it will recycle the row view for performance reasons. The problem is that in your `SimpleCursorAdapter` you override the  `newView()` method which will be called **only** when the ListView doesn't have a recycled view. Override `bindView()` to do the work as that method is called for each row, in the `newView()` method just inflate/build the row layout.

Comment: Now I see the importance of bindView(). Just a question. The newView() and bindView() should have the same code?. Whats the difference?.

Comment: @kiduxa The `newView()` method should be responsible only for building the row view(inflating a layout, programatically constructing the row etc). In the `bindView()` is where you'll actually bind the data from the `Cursor` to the views of the row that is passed in. You shouldn't mix them.

Comment: ok, I have edited my question. The newView and bindView should look like this, right?. Actually I dont have the need of override  de newView() method, rigth?

Comment: yes it works, but now I see that I dont have to override the  newView() method. The bindView() is all what I need. Right?

Comment: @kiduxa If you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` yes, the row will be built  based on the layout id that you pass in the constructor.

Comment: Luksprog since you have experience with this topic. I'm facing a new problem: For each row I have a text view and a edit text also. Depending on one condition, the edit text will show or not. For now, in my layout I have  android:visibility="invisible". But I get the same issue that I had before, when I change the orientation of the tablet, the rows with edit text shows correctly or not. I have edited my code in the solution part. If you have the time please take a look.

Comment: @kiduxa The changing of visibility should happen in the `bindView()` method(the `newView()` method is strictly for inflating the row layout, any other logic regarding how this row looks should be placed in the `bindView()` method). Also, always provide an alternative to whatever piece of code you have that changes the row's appearance, for example : `if(!uniMedition.equals("none")){...} else { EditText etMedida = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextMedida);
        etMedida.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); ...}` .

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right. I changed my layout and erased the part of code android:visibility="invisible". And then I changed the code as you suggested. I just don't get why this behavior, maybe it needed me to be more specific about how to show things. Now it works fine. Thanks again Luksprog :).

Comment: @kiduxa There is a video from one of the Google I/O events named `The world of ListView`. Watch it and it should clear many question regarding `ListView` and adapters in general.